# A function that creates a lists with input from another function

Tags: python, list, function, iteration

I have a function that will run a couple of times (in a recursive function, so with a 'while' condition). Everytime it runs, it will `return` a certain integer. So for example, the first time it runs it `returns` a `3`, the second time a `5` and the third time a `9`.

Now I need to save these `returns` in a list. So I thought to create a separate function that would take these values and store them. So the endstate I'm looking for is to have a `list = [3,5,8]`.

```
B = [3,6,5,7,8,10]
def function_1(A):
    for i in range(len(A)/2):
         factor = A[2*i]
         list_of_diagonals(factor)
    return factor`

def list_of_diagonals(d):
    factor_list = []
    factor_list = factor_list.append(d)
    return factor_list`
```

Now I would expect that `print function_1(B)` would produces `[3,5,8]` but instead it just produces `8`.

I think it has something to do with the fact that I define `factor_list=[]` right at the start of the function, but how could I work around that?

Comment: You are just returning `factor` from `function_1` which holds the last iterated value of `A[2*i]`

Comment: Have you tried using `yield` yet?

Comment: I don't think "recursive" is the same as a "while" condition. You also don't have a `while` statement in your code anywhere. Just a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `yield`. But I return `factor` in the first function, just to make sure I could use it in the second. I return `factor_list` in the second, so I could use it later, right?

Comment: @gilch: the recursive function is not in this piece of code because it's not needed for the problem I have. I just stated it so you know what I'm working on in the bigger picture.

Comment: A few thoughts at the beginning to clarify, so that less misunderstanding happens hopefully: 1. definitions you want to use have to be defined _before_, so the order, in which you define your functions will not work. 2. just calling a function more than once, e.g. in a while loop, has nothing to do with _recursion_ 3. `while` is not a condition, it's a loop

Comment: @SpghttCd The function has to be defined before it's *called*, not before it appears in another definition. Python just looks up the name in the globals dict at runtime. I don't see any problem with the order of the functions.

Comment: @gilch I see, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Use `range(int(len(A)/2))` instead of `range(len(A)/2)`. You can’t get a range from a float.

Answer (score 3):

using generator you can do this this way , better , readable and more pythonic

```
B = [3,6,5,7,8,10]
def function_1(A):
    for i in range(len(A)//2):
         factor = A[2*i]
         yield factor

result = list(function_1(B))
# output [3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: @Mathbeginner that's the `yield` I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

you are creating empty factor_list every time whenever list of diagonals call happens. Actually you don't need another function to store result in list , try below code:

```
B = [3,6,5,7,8,10]
def function_1(A):
    l1 = []
    for i in range(len(A)/2):
         factor = A[2*i]
         l1.append(factor)
    return l1
print function_1(B)
```

Comment: have you checked before posting. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @VineethSai what is not working here can you explain?  Yes.. it is working I am getting desired output `[3, 5, 8]`

Comment: Maybe it's the issue with range being a generator in python3.x

Comment: `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Strange.. At my end its working fine.. I am using python ... Are you using same B list?

Comment: Its the problem with `/` , have to replace it with `//` for python3.x , The integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Other users already pointed the option to use a list directly in the first method, but I'd suggest one way to refactor your code to make it work.

```
def function_1(array):
    list_of_diagonals_ = [] # <-- initialize the recipient
    for i in range(len(array)//2): # <-- # // to return integer
         factor = array[2*i]
         list_of_diagonals_ = list_of_diagonals(factor, list_of_diagonals_) # <-- call the function and store to recipient
    return list_of_diagonals_ # <-- return the recipient

def list_of_diagonals(element, factor_list = None): # <-- need an argument to memorize past results
    if factor_list == None: factor_list = [] # <-- just in case
    factor_list.append(element)
    return factor_list

B = [3,6,5,7,8,10]
print (function_1(B))
#=> [3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: NIce one, I appreciate it and it's definitely useful for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The following codes is under Python2.7

using islice in itertools can handle your case

```
from itertools import islice

B = [3, 6, 5, 7, 8, 10]


def function_1(A):
    return islice(A, 0, None, 2)

# [3, 5, 8]
print(list(function_1(B)))
```